# jQuery: It seems as if the script is ignoring the conditional (inside window.resize function)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn jQuery, because it is aparently easy. And given that I know enough HTML and CSS, I decided to try to emulate windows 10's left side menu of cortana, but in a website.

First I implemented the tab script, then the open on click script, then the close on clicking outside the menu script. Everything great until then, except when I decided I also wanted to make it mobile friendly, so I had to make the menu's width a percentage. I hide the menu with the left attribute, as it is fixed positioned. That also meant I had to deal with the left value in the script (at least, I don't think it is possible through CSS. Percentages don't work too well).

**I put left changing attribute script inside a window resize function so it is only triggered when the window size changes. Which I placed inside a conditional so it only triggers when the menu is not opened. The resizing works, it is triggered, but it is triggered always when a resizing happens, regardless if the menu is open or not and I have no idea why this is happening or what am I doing wrong.**

**Here is a JSFiddle (for some reason the set left attribute script doesn't work there, but it does on Chrome and Firefox):**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
    .menu {
        width:60%;
        background:rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.89);
        position:fixed;
        height:100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition:0.5s;
    }
    html,body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
    }
    #wrap {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .menu-tabs {
        display:block;
        width:55px;
        float:right;
        height:100%;
        padding:0 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition:0.5s;
    }
    .menu-tabs > div {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:45px;
        margin: 5px 0;
        background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
        transition:0.2s;
    }
    .menu-tabs:hover {
        background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43)!important;
    }
    .menu-tabs > div:hover {
        background:rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.46);
    }
    .menu-content > div {
        display:none;
        overflow:auto;
        padding:20px;
        height:100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-tabs">
            <div href="#1tab"></div>
            <div href="#2tab"></div>
            <div href="#3tab"></div>
            <div href="#4tab"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-content">
            <div id="1tab">First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab contentFirst tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab contentFirst</div>
            <div id="2tab">Second tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content 
            First tab content First tab content First tab content First tab content</div>
            <div id="3tab">Third tab content</div>
            <div id="4tab">Fourth tab content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrap">"asdadasd
    asdadasdas
    datasd
    asdadasdasd
    asdadasdasda
    sd</div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
            var menuWidth = $(".menu").width();
            var menuTabsWidth = $(".menu-tabs").width();
            $(".menu").css({left:'-' + (menuWidth - menuTabsWidth - 6)});
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var menuWidth = $(".menu").width();
            var menuTabsWidth = $(".menu-tabs").width();
            if ($(".menu").css('left')!= '0') {
                $(".menu").css({left:'-' + ($(".menu").width() - $(".menu-tabs").width() - 6)});
            }
            return;
        });
            $("#wrap").click(function(){
            var menuWidth = $(".menu").width();
            var menuTabsWidth = $(".menu-tabs").width();
                $(".menu").css({left:'-' + (menuWidth - menuTabsWidth - 6)});
                $(".menu-tabs").css({background:''});
                $(".menu-tabs > div").css({background:''}); 
            });
        $(".menu-tabs > div").click(function(){
            if ($(".menu").css('left')!= '') {
                $(".menu").css({left:0});
                $(".menu-tabs").css({background:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43)'});
            }
            $(".menu-tabs > div").css({background:''});     
            $(this).css({background:'rgb(0, 102, 255)'});
            $(".menu-content > div").hide();
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3wrwsp3z/

I hope anyone knows what's going on and what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You've circumvented the checks that tries to prompt you to include the code in your actual question.

Comment: the condition `if (!$(".menu").css('left')== '0') `  should use `!=`,  `if ($(".menu").css('left') != '0') `

Comment: @Jamiec Well, first time I tried it looked very messy. Didn't realise (or read) that the indent had to be in every line. Anyways, edited it.

Nikhil Girraj Thanks, I changed that, but the conditional is still being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Trying around I changed the conditional to `<=`. I don't know why, but that fixed it.

I still don't know why it isn't working in JSFiddle, though.